Predict COVID spread using latitude and longitude and time
I have a data that has latitude and longitude of individuals and the timestamp of geographical locations. I want to predict the spread of COVID using R using latitude/longitude and the time as well. I am quantifying spread as likelihood of covid infection using 1.8m social distancing threshold. Any idea in R or Python (though I am not vast in Python) will be welcome.
. What I did so far was to find pairwise comparison among individuals within each minute, and arrived at 
Any idea is welcome.

Hi William. Is it meant to be a serious analysis and not an exercise? If so, it would be a good idea to ask epidemiologists if your intended analysis is reasonable. You might get useful feedback at https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com. Also, I'd be wary of the quality of the data you intend to use (How the data has been collected? e.g. could people deactivate the tracking device they were using, if any? Is there possibly some bias in the selection of people whose behavior has been recorded? etc.). In addition, it looks like there's a non-negligible risk of omitted-variable bias here.
